# Cypress - QueryString parameters serializer

Tags: cypress

Hi everyone I'm using Cypress.io for API Integration Tests.

I need to make a GET request with the following query params.

`[GET] /exampleapi.com?type=1&type=2`

Cypress is serializing this url as

`/exampleapi.com?type[]=1&type[]=2`

But it does not work for me. I'm trying to change this behavior. Any ideas?

Can't do this using cy.intercept()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `qs` property that can be passed into a cy.request command. Also - just by looking at the URL provided, was there a misspelling? It seems odd to have the same query parameter with two values.